# Can I use Replicate in this manner during a SET operation in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to add some characters to data in a table using the following SQL query

```
UPDATE NAMES
SET FULL_NM = LTRIM(RTRIM(FULL_NM)) + REPLICATE('A', (SELECT max_length FROM sys.tables t2
                INNER JOIN sys.columns c
                    ON c.object_id = t2.object_id
                    where t2.name = 'NAMES' and c.name = 'FULL_NM') -LEN(FULL_NM))
```

The NAMES table has a Full Name column that has a length of 200, I want to fill up the rest of the space with A's.  When I run a select query that does the REPLICATE and displays the result next to the actual data it works fine, I see the original data, and data with A's that fill up the length.

Running the UPDATE statement I get an error regarding:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated.

I'm unsure how the length would get too long unless the REPLICATE is not working correctly the way I have it set.  Is there a way to get this update statement to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select character_maximum_length from databasename.[information_schema].columns
 where table_name = 'NAMES' and column_name = 'FULL_NM'

UPDATE NAMES
SET FULL_NM = LTRIM(RTRIM(FULL_NM)) + REPLICATE('A', (select character_maximum_length from databasename.[information_schema].columns
 where table_name = 'NAMES' and column_name = 'FULL_NM') -LEN(FULL_NM)-1)
```

Comment: Actually wasn't aware of information_schema, thanks a lot!